# Remove unnecessary rows in four columns and make a new column from one of them in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a `CSV` file that has multiple columns. Each `ID` in the `date` column has two rows. One with an `acronym` and the second row with the `date`. I want to remove all the even rows that have the `acronyms` in the `date` column and make `another` `column` out of these `rows`. Moreover, I would also like to remove the blank rows in columns `Date_Approved`, `SR` and `Permit`.

How can I do this in `R` using the `tidy` ways?

Sample Data

```
    Date = c("SB",
         "1/4/2021", 
         "HC/SB",
         "1/5/2021",
         "NC",
         "1/6/2021",
         "HC",
         "1/13/2021")

Date_Approved = c(" ",
                  "1/4/2021",
                  " ",
                  "1/8/2021",
                  " ",
                  "1/12/2021",
                  " ",
                  "1/15/2021")

SR = c(" ",
       "1A",
       " ",
       "1B",
       " ",
       "1C",
       " ",
       "1D")

Permit = c(" ",
       "AAA",
       " ",
       "BBB",
       " ",
       "CCC",
       " ",
       "DDD") 

Owner_Agent = c("Joe",
                "Joey",
                "Ross",
                "Chandler",
                "Monica",
                "Rachel",
                "Ed",
                "Edd")

Address = c("1111 W. Broward Boulevard",
            "Plantation, 33317",
            "2222 N 23 Avenue",
            "Hollywood, FL 33020",
            "3333 Taylor Street",
            "Hollywood, 33021",
            "44444 NW 19th St",
            "5555 Oak St")     

df = data.frame(Date,
                Date_Approved,
                SR,
                Permit,
                Owner_Agent,
                Address)
```

Snapshot

[image]

Code

```
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(Date,
                Date_Approved,
                SR,
                Permit,
                Owner_Agent,
                Address)

# Remove even rows with Acronyms and make a column out of them   
# Stuck
```

Comment: You could write a function that only reads every other row and then save that in a vector. From there read in your dataframe, remove all rows with NA in date approved and then append your vector with `cbind()`

Comment: Or you could use a lag function

Comment: There are a lot of errors from your sample data. Please check and update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple using the `lag()` function, assuming that there is only one space between every "correct" row.

See below:

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(Date, Date_Approved, SR, Permit, `Owner/Agent`, Address) %>% 
  mutate(Acronym = lag(Date)) %>% 
  filter(Date_Approved != " ")
```

This is also assuming that the empty value in the other columns is a " " and not `NA`

If it is `NA` replace the last line with `filter(!is.na(Date_Approved))`

Resulting data frame below:

```
       Date Date_Approved Acronym .....
1  1/4/2021      1/4/2021      SB
2  1/5/2021      1/8/2021   HC/SB
3  1/6/2021     1/12/2021      NC
4 1/13/2021     1/15/2021      HC
```

Comment: I am getting this `error` on the `original` dataset `Problem while computing Acronym = lag(Date).
x Acronym must be size 334 or 1, not 8. `

Comment: That probably means that it's returning a vector instead of a single value. Not sure why that would be happening, I would have to see your data. Can you share your code?

Comment: Sorry, but I was writing the column names wrong, the code is working, cheers.

Comment: It could be if your dataset is grouped. If you do `ungroup()` before the `mutate()` you can check if this is the case.